# Wordpress plugin: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Tags: wordpress

I messed around in the code of a plugin for woocommerce (paypal for woocommerce). After that I couldnt open the website or reach the backend to deactivate the plugin. I managed to restore my page, I had a back up. I can open the website and use the backend, except plugins. When I click plugins or move to specific pages on my website I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in /home/arabst8/public_html/abaya-store/wp-content/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/classes/wc-gateway-paypal-express-angelleye.php on line 997
```

This is line 977 of that file:

```
if( $this->skip_final_review == 'yes' && ( get_option('woocommerce_enable_guest_checkout') === "yes" && apply_filters('woocommerce_enable_guest_checkout', get_option('woocommerce_enable_guest_checkout')) == "yes" || is_user_logged_in() )) {
```

I am suprised that a full restore from a backup didnt fix it? I also deleted the plugin via FTP and STILL received the message, which was even stranger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, its fixed now but maybe it would be good if someone would still explain the issue for other people who get this error. Because my fix was sort of random:

1. I run a chaching plug in (W3 total cache). I tried to purge all cache earlier and it didnt do much. I didnt it again. Right after that:
2. I managed to go directly to the "Editor" function of plugins, I choose the file in question and without changing anything in the code I clicked "update".

That did it. Because I didnt test after the Purge I dont know if it was that or the second update. But it works again now.